# Show-hide list elements

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamically generated list as follows:

```
<ul>
<?php

 $currentYear = null;
 foreach($months as $m => $month){

    if(is_null($currentYear) || $currentYear !== $month->year){
        echo '<li id="year-'.$month->year.'"><strong>' . $month->year . '</strong></li>';
    }

    echo '<li class="'.$month->year.'"><a href="/news?year=' . $month->year . '&month=' . $month->month . '">' . date("M", strtotime($month->year . '-' . $month->month)) . ' (' . $month->total . ')</a></li>';

    $currentYear = $month->year;
}

?>
</ul>
```

which generates HTML like so:

```
<ul>
 <li><h2>2014</h2></li>
 <li><a href="/news?year=2014&amp;month=6">Jun (2)</a></li>
 <li><a href="/news?year=2014&amp;month=3">Mar (1)</a></li>
 <li><a href="/news?year=2014&amp;month=2">Feb (1)</a></li>
 <li><a href="/news?year=2014&amp;month=1">Jan (2)</a></li>
 <li><h2>2013</h2></li>
 <li><a href="/news?year=2013&amp;month=11">Nov (1)</a></li>
 <li><a href="/news?year=2013&amp;month=10">Oct (2)</a></li>
 <li><a href="/news?year=2013&amp;month=9">Sep (1)</a></li>
 ...
</ul>
```

I need the list items (li's) to be hidden initially, upon clicking on a heading 2014 say, all news items belonging to year=2014 would show or display. The same would happen for all headings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
$('ul li:has(a)').hide();

$('ul li :header').click(function(){
  $(this).parent('li').nextUntil('li:has(:header)').toggle();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phgAG/)

Comment: @AndrewCookson glad to help..! and what did you mean by `That's an excellent start` because i am not a native english speaker.. :)

Comment: I meant that's a good starting point - for me to build on should I need to - although it is a complete solution. Thanks again.